# Do I need to include family pictures when applying for a UK Visitor Visa?

Tags: visas, uk

Do I need to add any family/wedding photographs after adding marriage certificate and kids birth certificate.

Do I need a cover letter and what details should I show on the cover letter.

Comment: To what end are you including your family status in your visit visa application?

Comment: I'm married with kids and I need to show proof and I want to know if adding wedding photographs with marriage cert reasonable or not needed.

Comment: But why do you need to show proof?  Are you visiting your wife and kids, or are you showing ties to your home country, or are you traveling with them?

Comment: Oh OK..Sorry for the confusion.I'm showing ties to my home country and I am not travelling with them.

Comment: The guidance tells you what documents to submit. I would not supply anything they do not ask for. If they wanted pictures of your family, they surely know how to tell you that in the guidance.

Comment: If I have it right, you plan to visit the UK by yourself and your wife and kids will remain at the marital home. And in this situation you want to show strong ties to your home country. Have I got it right???

Comment: I have edited my post to get more response to my questions.

Comment: @ AdeK you have edited your post such as to change your main question. That is not how our site works and you will not get a better answer because of this, only now people will be confused by the good answer you already have. I did a roll back (i.e. undo your edits) so that your main question again is about the photos. As suggested by @GayotFow please do ask a **new** question about "What should a good cover letter contain?" and give all relevant details about circumstances right away in your question. It is all said in the answer here, did you even bother reading it?

Comment: I did read the answer and I thought if I edit the question instead of asking in a new post.I guess I was wrong.the answer was very explanatory.how do I vote do for it.

Comment: @AdeK good, no problem :) you can upvote the answer by clicking the up arrow above the number, also you did a good thing by accepting it with the check-mark! +1 to your question from me. Please go ahead and ask a new question about the cover letter, I think it would be valuable not only for you but also for others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears that you may have it cross-wired.

People use photos, like wedding photos and family photos, when they are applying for a *spouse visa or fiance visa*.  They think that photos will help prove that the marriage is genuine and not a sham marriage.  These are 'settlement visas' meaning that the spouse is coming to live in the UK permanently so they don't need to show round-trip tickets and the decision-makers do not care about ties to their native country and all the other things a visitor has to show. The place to ask more questions about those visas is [Expats](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions).

You are, on the other hand, contemplating a *visit visa* which is an altogether  different topology. Photos for visit visas rarely make it out of the mailroom. For the most part, they are irrelevant because you need to prove different things.

> Do I need to add any family/wedding photographs after adding marriage
>   certificate and kids birth certificate.

Why? If you want to prove you are married you can include a *certified* copy of your marriage certificate (or the original if you are confident they will return it).  Along the same lines, children's birth certificates are redundant to their passports. If they want a full-on DNA test to prove out the distaff or spear side lineage, they will call you in.

As a general rule, if you send in lots of irrelevant stuff they will conclude (and rightly so) that you have not studied the [guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/490874/Visitor_guidance_v4_0.pdf) and the [supporting documents list](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf). This weakens your application because how can you be trusted to follow the rules if you don't know what they are?

So study the guidance.

> Do I need a cover letter and what details should I show on the cover
>   letter.

A cover letter does not appear anywhere in the rules; it is not required. On the other hand a well-crafted, word-smithed cover letter can carry the application and sometimes the results border on miraculous. It means a mediocre application becomes a strong one. Sadly, a sloppy, poorly-crafted letter hurts the application so you need to think it over carefully. UK solicitors with a specialty in visit visas are the best at cover letters if you decide you want to go that route.

As to what points a cover letter should address, we have an open question about that [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco). So it's *technically* a duplicate.  The sole answer (at the moment) takes up a different case than yours. If another answer doesn't appear in the next few days, you can simply use the "ask question" button and ask a highly focused question about what to write. You would need to give a few details about your circumstances (i.e., your current question does not contain enough details/information to get a meaningful answer and users have been attempting to extract the details in comments -- it's a less focused thing and people lose interest going back and forth in comments to get the relevant information so try to make your question complete with respect to details and your personal circumstances).

Comment: `if question_tag in ('uk', 'visa') and answer_by = 'gayot-fow': upvote()`