# When traveling from Brazil to the UK, is an invitation letter required?

Tags: visas, uk, invitation-letters, brazilian-citizens

I am a British citizen, and am going to be hosting a friend of mine who's travelling over from Brazil to the UK for ~3 weeks, for the entirety of his trip.

We've checked online, and it appears that they don't need a visa or anything like that, however the brazilian website says that border officers in the UK appear to ask for documents like "letters of invitation" for Brazilian people travelling to the UK?

Is this letter necessary? And if so, does it need to be notarised? Are there any other documents he'd need beside his passport?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official UK website states that Brazilian citizens do not need a visa to visit the UK for up to 6 months. It goes on to mention documents that may be needed at the UK border:

> You must provide a valid passport or travel document. Your passport should be valid for the whole of your stay in the UK.

> You may also be asked to prove that:

> - you’re visiting for tourism
> - you’re able to support yourself and your dependents during your trip (or have funding from someone else to support you)
> - you’ve arranged accommodation for your stay
> - you’re able to pay for your return or onward journey (or have funding from someone else)
> - you’ll leave the UK at the end of your visit

So yes, as you’re hosting his stay you should provide an invitation (which does not need to be notarised), and your guest should bring documents to prove he meets the other eligibility criteria eg bank statements, employment contract etc, if asked.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y

Comment: Thank you for the reply!! That really clears some stuff up. I suppose the only other question we would have would be, does the letter need to be physical? And if so, does it need to be the original, mailed over to brazil for him to bring? I would think myself that him bringing a simple printed PDF would suffice, but I just want to confirm that

Comment: @Wazbat The guidance doesn’t specify the format https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk An email or a signed letter / pdf should be fine. There’s some advice on the content of an invitation letter in this question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco