# Why are they helping to pay for your visit?

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, standard-visitor-visas, proof-provenance-of-funds

How do I respond to this question when my sister is sponsoring my UK visit?

> Why are they helping to pay for your visit?

Comment: Is your sister a UK resident who you will visit? The way you should respond to questions is to tell the truth. We don't know why she is sponsoring you.

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco

Answer (score 7):

In this specific case, Basic answer would be : because she's my sister and she loves me.
(duh).

But as stated in comments, you should state the truth... And if you don't really know why your sister is helping you (and don't think family love is plausible), then best thing to do is to ask her.