# Visit the United Kingdom from South America: proving where we stay

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, visa-free-entry, south-america

My parents are going to visit the United Kingdom from South America. I have checked UK's site and they do not need a visa.

Only one requirements is not clear enough to me, and that is whether they ask for proof of where they are going to stay.

Would they be asked for proof of accommodation or just a passport and tickets?

My parents would be staying with me (in the UK), and they don't have hostel/hotel receipts.

That's why I would like to have a clear idea. Also I am not sure an invitation letter would be of any help, since as I said they do not need a Visa.

Comment: *"I am not sure an invitation letter would be of any help, since as I said they do not need a Visa."* But you are asking about proof of where they will be staying, not visas. Do you think such a letter will be harmful to their processing at immigration, or do you think it might help? Imagine a conversation with the immigration officer: "Where will you be staying?" "With our son/daughter." "Who are they? Where do they live? Are they expecting you...?" At which point they show your letter which contains every detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response for non-visa nationals from the UK [*Check if you need a UK visa* tool](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa) typically includes a statement about what visitors will need at the border.

Your parents may be asked to prove that:

> - they’re visiting for tourism
> - they’re able to support themselves and during the trip (or have funding from someone else to support them)
> - they’ve arranged accommodation for their stay
> - they’re able to pay for their return or onward journey (or have funding from someone else)
> - they’ll leave the UK at the end of their visit

You are sponsoring their accommodation. They should definitely have an invitation letter from you as proof of that. If you’re not a British citizen, you might also want to provide them with evidence of your immigration status in the UK.

Source: [Immigration Rules V4.2 and 4.3](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor)

Comment: Could you briefly explain what you have in mind by invitation letter? (for the visa this requires loads of paper work and be sent to embassy, I guess you don't mean that type of letter since this is for a border office.)

Comment: @MahNeh I mean just an invitation letter. [This question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/69228/what-should-a-sponsor-tell-the-eco) covers suggested content